# hdf5 error when format=table, pandas pytables

Tags: python, pandas, hdf5, pytables, hdf

It seems that I get an error when `format=table` but no error with `format=fixed`.  Here is the command.  What's weird is that it still seems to load the data. I just have to figure out a way to move past this. And it would give me peace of mind to not have any error. The dataframe is preprocessed, types set within the columns.

The command I run is:

`hdf = pd.HDFStore('path-to-file')`

`hdf.put('df',df,format='table')`

The error I get is:

```
HDF5ExtError: HDF5 error back trace

  File "../../../src/H5Dio.c", line 182, in H5Dread
    can't read data
  File "../../../src/H5Dio.c", line 550, in H5D__read
    can't read data
  File "../../../src/H5Dchunk.c", line 1837, in H5D__chunk_read
    unable to read raw data chunk
  File "../../../src/H5Dchunk.c", line 2863, in H5D__chunk_lock
    unable to read raw data chunk
  File "../../../src/H5Fio.c", line 113, in H5F_block_read
    read through metadata accumulator failed
  File "../../../src/H5Faccum.c", line 258, in H5F_accum_read
    driver read request failed
  File "../../../src/H5FDint.c", line 142, in H5FD_read
    driver read request failed
  File "../../../src/H5FDsec2.c", line 725, in H5FD_sec2_read
    file read failed: time = Mon Nov 17 01:25:35 2014
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26963654/hdfstore-start-stop-not-working?noredirect=1#comment42467626_26963654

Comment: pls read the extensive docs: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#hdf5-pytables; sounds like you want append which is not possible with a fixed store - not enough code to tell what you are actually doing

Comment: fascinating... I defined a method I pulled from another SO page: def chunker(seq, size):
    """given an array with a __getitem__ attribute
     and size of chunks return an iterator of array"""
    return (seq[pos:pos + size] for pos in range(0, len(seq), size))

Comment: Then when I run this with `hdf.append` rather than `hdf.put` it works.  Not only that, when I do the whole thing with hdf.append it seems to work, but only sometimes.... I think I'd rather just treat this in chunks. I will move on, and hope to optimize this later.